# Compile nib2objc (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I don't know if anyone has ever used nib2objc to convert .nib and .xib files into code (I have to do this for a college class), but I am having trouble compiling this. I downloaded version 1.3 from the github page https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc but when I try opening the project with Xcode, nothing happens. Anyone know how to get this thing running so that I can view the command line, and get the code for my .xib files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The 1.3 version of nib2objc isn't really up to snuff. Luckily, a co-worker of mine has made some excellent improvements.

Pro tip: nib2objc doesn't understand subclassed UI items. So if you have a custom UIButton subclass "MyButton", just refer to it as a UIButton* in Interface Builder and recreate it as a MyButton in your code (you'll have to copy the original UIButton's frame and other properties in your MyButton init).

The code is on this fork: https://github.com/davidjackman/nib2objc

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! Just one more question: Which directory or folder should I open using Xcode? aka how do you compile this thing? Whenever I try to open any of the folders with Xcode, nothing happens.

Comment: You'll want to use the "Command Line.xcodeproj" in the "Command Line" folder. This will create a "nib2objc" executable that takes in a .xib and outputs a .m file.